# Just ping a mongodb-server, not connect just ping

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu

from server1 I need to check via NodeJs if the mongodb-servers on server2, server3, etc.. are running. But I dont want to connect or any other action for which I would need the mongodb-credentials.

Is that somehow possible? Or maybe someone can suggest a other good way to check if monggo on a other server is running fine?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [ping](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/ping/) command for this task that do not require authentication:

```
mongo --eval 'db.adminCommand({ping: 1})'
```

For node.js there is nice example in the official docs here:

[ping example node.js](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/admin.html#ping)

just replace localhost with your mongo server hostname/IP and port here:

```
new Server('localhost', 27017));
```

another [example](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/fundamentals/connection/connect/#std-label-node-connect-to-mongodb):

```
 const { MongoClient } = require("mongodb");
 // Connection URI
 const uri =
 "mongodb+srv://sample-hostname:27017/?maxPoolSize=20&w=majority";
 // Create a new MongoClient
 const client = new MongoClient(uri);
 async function run() {
 try {
 // Connect the client to the server (optional starting in v4.7)
 await client.connect();
 // Establish and verify connection
 await client.db("admin").command({ ping: 1 });
 console.log("Connected successfully to server");
 } finally {
  // Ensures that the client will close when you finish/error
  await client.close();
 }
 }
 run().catch(console.dir);
```

Comment: Thank yoo very much for your answer. That youl ruquire SSH-Connection, but what if the NodeJS-Script runs on a other machine?

Comment: updated my answer , in node.js you can do: db.ping() using your database remote hostname or IP address.